# Your Android App Bundle has more than 1 certificate chain. Ensure your App Bundle has only 1 certificate chain and try again

Tags: azure, maui, pipeline, digital-signature, release

I have an Issue when trying to release my Android app to Play store sing Azure pipeline. Below is my yml file,im using Maui .NET8 Thank you.

NB: I have another pipeline that also sign in the other app to same Play store

`- stage: BuildAndroid
displayName: Build Android
jobs:

- job: BuildAndroidJob
  pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

  steps:

  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
    script: 'dotnet workload install maui'
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET sdk'
    inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: 8.0.x
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
  - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
    displayName: Configure Java version
    inputs:
    versionSpec: '11'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'
  - task: android-manifest-version@1
    displayName: Version Android build
    inputs:
    sourcePath: 'path/to/AndroidManifest.xml'
    versionCodeOption: 'buildid'
    versionCode: '$(Build.BuildId)'
    versionName: '$(buildVersionPrefix).$(Build.BuildId)'
    versionCodeOffset: '10000'
    printFile: true
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    displayName: Install nuget tool
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.sln'
    arguments: '-c Release -f net8.0-android'
  - task: AndroidSigning@2
    displayName: 'Sign .aab'
    inputs:
    apkFiles: '**/*.aab'
    jarsign: true
    jarsignerKeystoreFile: '$(KeyStoreSecureFileName)'
    jarsignerKeystorePassword: '$(KeystorePassword)'
    jarsignerKeystoreAlias: '$(Alias)'
    jarsignerKeyPassword: '$(AliasPassword)'
    jarsignerArguments: '-sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256'
    zipalign: true
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: Copy .apk to staging directory
    inputs:
    Contents: '**/*.apk'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    OverWrite: true
    flattenFolders: true
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: Copy .aab to staging directory
    inputs:
    Contents: '**/*.aab'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    OverWrite: true
    flattenFolders: true
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: Publish .apk and .aab
    inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'`

I have tried removing the signing in task but still I get an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ***AndroidSigning@2 task***, Use

```
GooglePlayRelease@4
```

with the GooglePlayConnectionService and run the pipeline.

Refer the blog ***[here](https://damienaicheh.github.io/azure/devops/2021/10/25/configure-azure-devops-google-play-en.html#)*** for the details steps.

Install the **`Official Google play extension`** in your ***Azure DevOps account*** from [**here**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.google-play):-

After the extension is installed Create a Private key and add an **Google Play Azure service connection** in Azure DevOps with the same Private key and Google play developer account.

[image]

My ***Azure DevOps yaml pipeline***:-

```yaml
jobs:
- job:
  displayName: 'Build and Publish to Google Play Store'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'

  steps:
  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: 'dotnet workload install maui'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET SDK'
    inputs:
      packageType: sdk
      version: 8.0.x
      installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

  - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
    displayName: 'Configure Java version'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '11'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'

  - task: android-manifest-version@1
    displayName: 'Version Android build'
    inputs:
      sourcePath: 'path/to/AndroidManifest.xml'
      versionCodeOption: 'buildid'
      versionCode: '$(Build.BuildId)'
      versionName: '$(buildVersionPrefix).$(Build.BuildId)'
      versionCodeOffset: '10000'
      printFile: true

  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    displayName: 'Install NuGet tool'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.sln'
      arguments: '-c Release -f net8.0-android'

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy AAB to artifacts directory'
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/YourMauiProject/bin/Release/net8.0-android/'
      Contents: '*.aab'
      TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      ArtifactName: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'Container'

  - task: GooglePlayRelease@4
    displayName: 'Publish to Google Play Store'
    inputs:
      serviceConnection: 'GooglePlayConnectionService'
      applicationId: 'com.yourcompany.yourapp'
      action: 'SingleBundle'
      bundleFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.aab' # Adjust the path accordingly
      track: 'internal'
```

The Pipeline worked without GooglePlayRelease@4 task too.

Reference [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/google-play-vsts-extension/issues/142)